# Elimination rule for finitely-bounded quantifiers

Tags: theorem-proving, quantifiers, isabelle

I have the following goal:

```
∀x ∈ {0,1,2,3,4,5}. P x
```

I want to break this goal down into the six subgoals `P 0`, `P 1`, `P 2`, `P 3`, `P 4` and `P 5`. This is easily done by `apply auto`. But what is the relevant rule that `auto` is using to do this? I ask because my actual goal looks more like this:

```
∀x ∈ {0..<6}. P x
```

and `apply auto` doesn't break that goal down in the same way (it gives me

```
⋀x. 0 ≤ x ⟹ x < 6 ⟹ P x
```

instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `[simp]` lemma to transform sets into more convenient versions of the set is very convenient. E.g. `{0..<6} = {0,1,2,3,4,5}`

Answer (score 2):

The rule that `auto` is using is `ballI` (bounded all introduction). This transforms `∀x ∈ S. P x` into `x ∈ S ==> P x`.

The issue of transforming `x ∈ {0,1,2,3,4,5}` into 6 separate subgoals is a separate one. Basically, `auto` transforms the explicit enumeration into a disjunction and then splits that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lemma such as the following to split out a single goal:

```
lemma expand_ballI: "⟦ (n :: nat) > 0; ∀x ∈ {0..< (n - 1)}. P x; P (n - 1) ⟧ ⟹ ∀x ∈ {0..< n}. P x"
  by (induct n, auto simp: less_Suc_eq)
```

which could then be repeatedly applied to your rule as follows:

```
lemma "∀x ∈ {0..< 6 :: nat}. P x"
  apply (rule expand_ballI, fastforce)+
  apply simp_all
```

resulting in the goals split out as follows:

```
goal (6 subgoals):
 1. P 0
 2. P (Suc 0)
 3. P 2
 4. P 3
 5. P 4
 6. P 5
```